# Dynamic drop down list - SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

this has been driving me mad... I have two dynamically created asp dropdown boxes, makes and models. When a user selects the makes, it calls an ASP button called makeChanged. When makeChanged runs, it is supposed to clear the items in the models drop down list and then create new ones. So the code for handling the makeChanged button is as follows:

```
Sub makeChanged (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

Dim thingID = sender.ID.split("_")(1)

Dim modelDD As DropDownList = thingsContainer.FindControl("model_" & thingID )
modelDD.EnableViewState = False
modelDD.Items.Clear()
modelDD.SelectedValue = -1
modelDD.AppendDataBoundItems = True

Dim select_qry = "select * from Models where makeid=" & sender.SelectedValue

Dim objData2 As SqlDataReader = getSqlQueryObj(select_qry)
modelDD.DataSource = objData2
modelDD.DataValueField = "models"
modelDD.DataTextField = "models"
modelDD.DataBind() 'This is where the error is getting triggered from

End Sub
```

I know for a fact there is nothing wrong with the query or finding the drop down because i have ran many response.write's and it comes back with the expected outcome. I thought that it might be due to the fact that viewState was preserving the old value on index changed and then trying to add it to the list after i re-populated the list with new values from the DB however i turned off viewState to check this and it still doesnt make a difference :|.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `SelectedValue` to `-1` which must exist. Don't confuse it with the `SelectedIndex` where `-1` indicates that nothing should be selected.

So i assume that you actually want:

```
' ...
 modelDD.Items.Clear()
 modelDD.SelectedIndex = -1  ' instead of SelectedValue = -1
' ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply however i also tried modelDD.SelectedIndex = -1 and i  still get the error.

Comment: @Rezzy: You have tried `carModel...` but the ID of the `DropDownList` is `modelDD`, isn't it?

Comment: Btw the follwing happens on my page:

Step1: Page loads-Creates the dropdownlist-populates its values from the Database via databind.

Step2: Make index is changed-the page load function would run again (it always does on any submit before a button/index change gets called) which creates the dropdownlist and sets its values to something old (exactly the same as step1). Then the index changed function fires after the page load, which tries the populate the dropdownlist again via databind. So this means that the dropdownlist is actually binded twice but i dont see why there might be a problem.

Comment: @Rezzy: Why do you need `AppendDataBoundItems` at all?

Comment: I dont actually lol, i was just desperately trying every solution i found online. Actually i think i just found the solution ....
I just added the line: "modelDD.SelectedValue = Nothing" before i did the databind which nulled the modelDD and it seemed to work!

Do you have any idea why on earth that resolved it? WHy is this behaviour happening i dont understand.

Comment: @Rezzy: Should be the same as what i have suggested (replace `SelectedValue` with `SelectedIndex`). Setting it to -1 is incorrect if you just want to deselect the list. It would only be correct if you would have added a "default-item" (for example `"--Please Select--"`) with a value of `-1` and you want to select this.

Comment: Yes i was trying to deselect the list and thought that setting it to -1 would have done the trick, apparently not...
Thanks Tim, I appreciate you helping me out :)